# How to split what I have after equal and between `""`?

Tags: c#

How to split what I have after equal and between `""`? I have a text file where one of the rows are like this : `PLP="some text"`, and I want to get just `some text` and put in other file. I use the next code, but this split `"some text"` and I want just `some text`:

```
if (txt.Contains("PLP="))
{
    var PLPPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
    newInstaller = newInstaller.Select(line => 
                         Regex.Replace(line,@"fileInstallationKey=.*",
                                      "fileInstallationKey=" + PLPPath));   
}
```

Comment: how about `txt.Split('=')[1].Replace('"', '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
txt.Split('=')[1].Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maor Veitsman's solution works. I just want to point out that, given the little input, another alternative (besides various others) would be splitting by the quotationmarks directly like so:

```
txt.Split(new[] { '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Trim` instead of `Replace`:

```
string res = txt.Split('=')[1].Trim(new char[] { '"' });

Console.WriteLine(res); // some text
```